# How to run a oracle sql file (*.sql) from php

Tags: php, oracle, adodb

How to run oracle sql file from PHP using Adodb

Comment: Read file contents and run queries as usual?

Answer (score 1):

If it's just a normal sql statement you could just read the file with file_get_contents and execute it.

```
$rs = $DB->Execute(file_get_contents('query.sql'));
```

Comment: Is there any way to pass the _filename_ to the Oracle client library? So that the library does the reading of it, instead of the caller doing it?

Comment: That wouldn't make sense, since the library needs to work everywhere, not only for your one script. :)

Comment: I don't think, you understood my question. What I'm looking for is some equivalent to `$DB->ExecuteFile('query.sql'))`. Is there such a thing?